# tkinter how do i save changes made to the buttons

Tags: button, tkinter

thx a lot for replying my questions for making my previous code simpler.. this is the result... now for the next phase is save changes made to the buttons.. im still learning though looking for sources anything can help :)

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

def onChange(i):
    btn_list[i].config(text='Updating...',bg='red')  
    btn_list[i].grid(in_=root,row=rw[i],column=2)
    ans=tk.simpledialog.askfloat('Updating....', 'What is the current price?')
    if ans:        
        btn_list[i].config(text='RM{:,.2f}'.format(ans))
        btn_list[i].config(bg='yellow') 

root=Tk()
Title=['Item','Unit','Price']
Item=['Kopi O','Teh O','Teh Tarik']
Unit= '1 cup'
Price=[1,0.9,1.2]
cl=[0,1,2]
rw=[1,2,3]
btn_list=[]

for i in range(3):
    btnT1=tk.Button(root,text=Title[i],width=10,bg='light green')
    btnT1.grid(in_=root,row=0,column=cl[i])

for x in range(3):
    btnT2=tk.Button(root,text=Item[x],width=10)
    btnT2.grid(in_=root,row=rw[x],column=0)

for y in range(3):
    btnT3=tk.Button(root,text=Unit,width=10)
    btnT3.grid(in_=root,row=rw[y],column=1)             

for z in range(3):
    btnT4=tk.Button(root,text=('RM {:,.2f}'.format(Price[z])),bg='yellow',width=10,\
                command=lambda i=z:onChange(i))
    btnT4.grid(in_=root,row=rw[z],column=2)
    btn_list.append(btnT4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want to update the Price list? Or if the user clicks the cancel button change it to what it was before it was clicked? Or something else?

Comment: Yeah.. I want to update the price list... if u hv ideas n suggestion cud go to general overview on how I cud b done... I add new button at the bottom name 'save changes'.. n myb assign function to save new price list.. or.. myb saving n updating the price list automatically without any additional button... wud like to hear ur point of view n suggestion thank you Steven :)

Comment: in the `onChange` function you can just put in the if statement `Price[i] = ans` since the index in the list matches the buttons as well

Comment: well the general issue is that it works like a loop.. passes one argument to another and update the current price as long as the loop active... but when deactivated or close the program its reboot to the old price.. how to make the new price stay permanently and the original price becomes irrelevant.. do I need to use filedialog or store the data somwhre so dat it cud recall everytime I open the program...

Comment: You would have to store it in a file to read on start-up and then overwrite the file each time you make a change.

Answer (score 1):

If you want changes to be saved when your program exits and restarts, you'll have to do all of the work yourself. You'll need to write a function that gathers all the data you want to save, another function to write that data to a file or database, a third to be able to read the data from the file or database, and a forth to update the UI with the saved values.